# How to place a Textview to the right and center of the Imageview in Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I want to place a textview to the right and gravity centre of the Image View. I am using Relative Layout for that. Using Relative Layout, i am able to set the Textview to the right side of the Image view.But not able to set it to the centre. I mean here center is not inside of the Imageview, i want to place Textview to the right centre of Imageview(outside centre of Imageview).I am not able to set to centre.
Anybody please help me out.I want to do this only in relative layout.

Here is my xml,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_text_view"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:textColor="@color/color_white"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/name_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/val_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/button"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with this code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="60dp">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="hello world"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
      >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/name_text_view"
      android:textSize="20sp"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image_view"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:textColor="@color/black"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
  </LinearLayout>
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:background="@color/blue"
      android:textColor="@color/color_white"
      android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
      android:layout_below="@id/name_text_view"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/val_text_view"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textColor="@color/black"
      android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
      android:textSize="18sp"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_below="@id/button"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in your textview

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do You want this view? then try this code.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/leaner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:contentDescription="TODO"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name:"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/val_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Value"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/leaner1"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:text="button"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```